# How to restart clipboard service on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, clipboard, windows-services

I have been experiencing problems pasting data as a *metafile* after a change in the display scaling (DPI settings) of my primary monitor on Windows 10. The only way to fix the problem so far is to log out and log back in.

I would like to try and restart the service responsible for clipboard management, but I can't find it. The only documentation I found refers to a **ClipSrv** under Windows XP...

If anyone knows how to restart the clipboard management service, I'd be very happy to hear about it!

Answer (score 15):

The simplest fix when clipboard functionality is not working is to open Task Manager (Ctrl + Shift + Esc) and select Windows Explorer from the Processes tab, then click "Restart". Be sure there are no file copy processes ongoing, and any open Windows Explorer windows will close, but it should restore your clipboard functions.

[Explorer Restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMF8g.png)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: This is not great advice, especially if you don't want to lose open folders. Restart the clipboard service first, or look into programs that might be be hogging clipboard such as Teamviewer. Would not have worked in my case, and would have lost my open folders.

Answer (score 11):

Just struggled around with my dead clipboard on Win10, build 19041.804.
Finally I could get it back by

- stop the Clipboard User Service in Services

  [image: Windows services, clipboard user service]
- then execute the following command in an elevated Powershell terminal
  `cmd /c "echo off |clip"`
  and
- restart the Clipboard User Service in Services again

**Howto stop and restart the service:** goto Search, type services, open Services and goto `Clipboard User Services`. Right click to Stop or Start the Service.

**Howto open an elevated Powershell terminal:** goto Search, type powershell and choose `Run as Administrator`.

Comment: This SEEMED to work, thank you for this! Let me edit your post to make it a bit more clear

Comment: just restarting the service worked for me

Comment: well darn, since I wrote that I have Windows 11 and I don't see a "Clipboard" service at all in Services (Local) any more 

Comment: Did not work for me even after restarting this service. Whatever sometimes breaks the clipboard seems to break it pretty badly that only a restart fixes it.

Comment: Does not work for me either in Windows 11.

Comment: I didn't see this service at first and wanted to try the _restart explorer_ solution. When I scrolled down in Task Manager to find _Windows Explorer_, I stumbled accross the actual service, which is surprisingly called _Zwischenablage-Benutzerdienst_ on my system, even though I have the language set to _English (US)_ everywhere. ‍♂️ And restarting that service helped, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Since there are other posts showing how to restart it, you could also consider clearing (if the restart doesn't work or if you want to try something else):

```
cmd /c "echo off | clip"
```

Comment: This clear the content of clipboard, do not restart the service!

Comment: I have the same issue, and entering the command above gives me "ERROR: Access is denied." error :(.

Comment: It does not restart the service, but if you have any trouble with the state of the clipboard service then this *may* fix it, as I found out. Strangely enough, just copying other data to the clipboard using Control-C / Paste didn't do it. Probably not true for everyone, but worth a try.

Answer (score 6):

I found a way to restart the clipboard service related to Windows 10's clipboard history <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

### Symptoms

No entries are added to the clipboard history anymore.

### Solution

1. Open Windows Settings:

   [image]
2. Toggle clipboard history off and on.

Comment: good idea but sadly this didn't work for me 

Answer (score 2):

As of my quick research, clipboard functionality is an integral part of `Win32k.sys` and there is no service responsible for the clipboard.

To address your problem, let's assume the data in the clipboard gets corrupted by some reason. Therefore, I would suggest you also to try to inspect the clipboard state after pasting the data into it.

To make the process more traceable you may try to load the data into the clipboard manually with PowerShell:

`Write-Output $data | Set-Clipboard`

You may also append items to the clipboard without replacing the existing content:

`Write-Output $data2 | Set-Clipboard -Append`

And check the clipboard content with:

`Get-Clipboard`

Comment: No longer true for Windows 10. It was moved into a `svchost.exe` service.

Comment: Not that that matters much, as that service is an integral part of Windows and cannot be restarted.

Answer (score 1):

Before restarting your PC, try closing your applications one by one, and test the clipboard. One of the apps could open the clipboard for exclusive access which prevents other apps from modifying the clipboard content.

Comment: iTunes was the culprit for me!

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, maybe it's related to the Clipboard User Service/cbdhsvc under Services (there will be 2, machine-wide and user-specific).

However, if anyone is doing all this work just to get Clipboard History to work, please don't. There is a much better, more stable, more lightweight, faster and more configurable option. Yes the last release is 2008, but wow I have barely seen 2/3 bugs over the last 8+ years. It's called ClipX, by BlueMars: https://bluemars.org/clipx/

If the site is down then find another one. Get ClipX (beta is good too). Immediately go to Configure via notification icon, select Hotkeys tab, delete all shortcuts and unselect all checkboxes, set only the Paste Menu (Primary) (Ctrl+Shift+V maybe?).

Also I recommend getting ClipX Limits Plugin with it (both as 32bit or both as 64 bit). And ticking the option to "Ignore text/bitmap ... larger than..." under the new Limits tab for the Configure screen.

Comment: The SW maybe fine but their web hygiene is chilling: "The certificate for bluemars.org expired on 2022/10/30"

Answer (score 1):

```
PS> Get-Service -DisplayName 'clip*' | Restart-Service

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  cbdhsvc_fbd8a      Clipboard User Service_fbd8a
```

Comment: for whatever reason in Windows 11 there _are_ no services called "Clipboard User Service" running

Comment: @JeffAtwood It may be because of CVE-2022-21869 https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/en-US/vulnerability/CVE-2022-21869

Answer (score 0):

Why You Can’t Able To Clear Clipboard In Windows 10
Where Windows 10 has lots of features, on the other hand, it has also lots of errors and problems. One of the major cause is its clipboard which automatically caught our copy-pasting and we lost our main clipboards, that’s frustrating.

It happens because of the windows feature, and to fix it I’ve several methods that are easy and effective. Let’s learn it step-by-step.

Let's fix this problem now

1. Clear Entire Clipboard History
2. [Clear Complete Clipboard Data](https://yourwindowshelper.com/clear-clipboard-windows-10/)
3. Clear Clipboard by pressing Windows Key + V.
4. Use Prnscrn Button.
5. Restart Your PC.
6. Add Clear Clipboard Option In Desktop Context Menu Using Registry

Comment: This is a non-solution as it involves rebooting.