# windows 10: why, do I have 2 "Clipboard User Service"? (What is the cbdhsvc_63366 windows service?)

Tags: windows-10, virus, clipboard

My clipboard ceased to work (it did not copy anything), so I look into the service to restart it. But I found 2 Clipboards User Service:
[image]

What is it? Is it legit?

Opening the key of this service I fund this duplication and number "63366" in several keys:
[image]

(I did fix my clipboard issue following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1628049/235752))

Comment: These are [per-user services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/per-user-services-in-windows). I'm sure we had an answer about that already.

Comment: @DanielB, thank you for your reply. You are right, it was a duplicate. I apologize.

Comment: No worries, with the random suffixes it’s hard to find.